# Tradingview pine script - count number of times price reached specific level

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I have some specific price levels on the chart and would like to count number of times price went to these levels.

For example: At timestamp T1 I have a price range R1. I want to see how many times price went back to that level and "pierced" through it.
Please note that the ranges are dynamic (some conditions need to be met) and there may be plenty of these ranges on the chart.

I have no idea where to start from so any help would be appreciated.